# How to Limit Duplicat Rows in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have data similar to for table : **fruit_table**

| Product Code | Product | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-25 |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-26 |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-27 |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-28 |
| BN | Banana | 2019-01-15 |
| BN | Banana | 2020-01-19 |
| BN | Banana | 2020-01-20 |
| BN | Banana | 2016-01-20 |
| AP | APPLE | 2021-03-02 |

As you can see in the data we have **Mango** 4 products and **Banana** 4 Products and **Apple** with 1 product, i want the solution is to limit the products with 2 rows with **latest date**.

And i want output similar to

| Product Code | Product | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-27 |
| MG | Mango | 2020-01-28 |
| BN | Banana | 2020-01-19 |
| BN | Banana | 2020-01-20 |
| AP | APPLE | 2021-03-02 |

How can this be achieved with a simple query in PostgreSQL query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e8129428ded46459f9f2cc329e3c273)

You can use [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to achieve that:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "Product Code" ORDER BY "Date" DESC)     -- 1
   FROM fruit_table
) s
WHERE row_number <= 2                                                            -- 2
```

1. `row_number()` adds a row count to each record in an ordered group (= partition). In your case the group is the `Product Code` (or `Product`) and you need to order each group by `Date DESC` to get the most recent dates to the top. Now the most recent date in each group gets the row count `1`, the second recent one the `2` and so on
2. Using this row count you can filter only the two top records of each group.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I'd appreciate if you could UPVOTE as well if not happened yet :)

Answer (score 1):

As a note:  If you have a separate table of products, then you might find that a lateral join is faster:

```
select ft.*
from products cross join lateral
     (select ft.*
      from fruit_table ft
      where ft.product = p.product
      order by ft.date desc
      limit 2
     ) ft;
```

Like the solution using `row_number()` this will take advantage of an index on `fruit_table(product, date)`.  However, I think the performance would usually be a little better (basically because it does not assign row number values to all rows before filtering them out).